# React todo list - how to make the filter work

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
handleFilters(filter){
   console.log(filter);
}

render(){
   return(
       <div>
          <a href="#" filter="show_all" onClick={this.handleFilters}>All</a>
          {'  '}
          <a href="#" filter="show_active">Active</a>
          {'  '}
          <a href="#" filter="show_completed">Completed</a>
     </div>
```

I am making a todo app and have it's working too, but I am having a bit of a problem adding the filters where I can show All todos, active todos, or the completed todos.

what I am trying to do at the moment is to get the value of filter from the a  href tags and then will use it to filter the todo items from the list.
but at the moment, I am just trying to get the value of filter, so how do I do that?

Comment: I think dpwrussell's answer in this thread may help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37930127/filtering-todo-list-in-react-js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could avoid storing data in DOM like this

```
const match = filter => () => this.handleFilters(filter)
<div>
          <a href="#" onClick={match('show_all')}>All</a>
          {'  '}
          <a href="#" onClick={match('show_active')}>Active</a>
          {'  '}
          <a href="#" onClick={match('show_completed')}>Completed</a>
     </div>
```

Comment: I am quite new to this, so could you explain a bit more?
aren't you still storing this in dom?

Comment: I create a handler for each link that has `filter` value stored in its scope. ES5 equvalent would be `this.handleFilters.bind(this, 'show_all')`. Techically yes I store data in DOM but in very indirect manner: as a value in scope of a handler. So I don't need to access real DOM node and access it's attributes or something.

Comment: umm, I guess I still need to read this a few more times before I understand this fully. could you provide a link to where I can read more about this thing you have used? 

anyways, what I want to do now is to pass this value of filter to the parent component, so could you tell me how to do that?

Comment: I have used arrow function [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) But as I wrote this is totally doable with [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)

Comment: no. I understood the arrow function part.
what I didnt understand was the bind portion.

anyways, could you tell how to pass the value of filter from the child to the parent?

Comment: @faraz pass a callback from parent to child.

Answer (score 0):

```
handleFiltersShowActive(){ 
     const tds = this.props.todos.foreach(todo => 
    if(!todo.isCompleted) 
    Displaytodolist.push(todo);
    );
    this.setState(displaytodo: tds);
    } 
    render(){ 
    {todos} = this.props;
    Let display = this.state.displaytodo.foreach( todo => 
visiblelist.push (
<div> {todo.title} </div>
);
);
    return( 
    <div> <a href="#" filter="show_all" onClick={this.handleFilters}>All</a> {' '}
     <a href="#" filter="show_active" onClick={this.handleFiltersShowActive}>Active</a> {' '}
     <a href="#" filter="show_completed">Completed</a> </div>

{display}
    )};
```

Try this out.